# Allow My App To Be Launched By Other Apps

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to launch one of my apps from within another one of my apps.

I've successfully tested launching apps like Google Chrome, but when I try my second app package name, the launch intent is null. I think my intent filter is wrong, but I can't figure it out. Here is what I'm doing in app 1:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.my.app");
if (launchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(launchIntent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "LAUNCH INTENT IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In the app 2 manifest, I have this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.my.app"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Any help much appreciated. I have looked at the documentation and a lot of answers on here but haven't found my solution!

Thanks!

Comment: You dont need an intent filter in com.my.app. The getPackageName() in com.my.app should be com.my.app. Thats all.

Comment: Wow, as simple as that. I tested it, and somehow getPackageName() was returning a different package from what it said at the top of the file. Thanks!